# How to know how much gas will be consumed for a specific action on the Ethereum blockchain?

Tags: gas

I'm new to Ethereum and can't wrap my head around the estimated gas for a particular contract. If the contract consists of code which calls on specific functions, why can't the Dapp tell me in advance EXACTLY how much gas the particular action will cost?

Answer (score 1):

The cost of some opcodes depends on the contract state. For example changing the content of one storage slot has different prices depending on the previous value stored (SSTORE opcode). It is possible for the same function to result in different costs.

There are some wallets like Metamask that before executing a transaction will simulate the execution and return the gas required to execute it successfully.